# How do I test drag and drop in Angular 2 unit tests

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am working on an `Ionic 2` app which has the functionality of tinder cards. I would like to test my card `throwout` events which happens when cards are dragged more than a limit. I am using [swing](https://github.com/gajus/swing) library.

> home.html

```
<div swing-stack #myswing1 [stackConfig]="stackConfig"  id="card-stack">
  <button ion-button icon-only *ngIf="hunts.length == 0" (click)="loadHunts()"><ion-icon name="refresh-circle"></ion-icon></button>
  <ion-card swing-card #mycards1 *ngFor="let hunt of hunts"  [navPush]="showHuntPage" [navParams]="{hunt: hunt}" >
    <ion-card-header>
      {{hunt.title}}
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <div><img width="150" height="250" [src]="imageSource(hunt.picture_url)"></div>
      <div>
        {{hunt.clue}}
      </div>
      <div>
        {{hunt.distance_from_user }} away
      </div>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

Each `ion-card` is `throwable` by dragging.

I do subscribe to `throwing` events in `home.ts` like this.

```
    this.throwRightSub =  this.swingStack.throwoutright.subscribe( (event: ThrowEvent) => {
      let hunt = this.hunts.shift();
      this.reviewHunt("accepted",hunt);
      this.events.publish("hunt-accepted",hunt);
    });
    this.throwLeftSub = this.swingStack.throwoutleft.subscribe( (event: ThrowEvent) => {
      let hunt = this.hunts.shift();
      this.reviewHunt("rejected",hunt);
    });
  }
```

I have seen click event being mocked with

```
let el = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('ion-card'));
el.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
```

Is there anyway to trigger `drag` event in unit test? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm also looking into this for my own project.